# Matlab gamfit equivalent function in boost

Tags: c++, matlab, boost, gamma-distribution

I'm looking for an equivalent function to gamfit in boost. Anyone knows if it is implemented a functionality like gamfit in boost library ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I implemented the MLE for the gamma distribution using the boost::math::tools::toms748_solve optimizer and digamma function.